# MorphX report designer: are there any alternatives?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

MorphX report designer in Ax 2009 seems to be not the 'best' as report designer.. I don't know if is my fault, or if morphx report designer too buggy to do his job. 
I'm guessing if there are some alternative to do report for Ax 2009: maybe Crystal Report and Visual Studio ? Or ... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSRS is the main alternative for AX 2009.  You can deploy the reporting extensions and analysis cubes for some good reporting data.  Analysis cubes will need to be configured to match your individual license file.

If you just want to be able to create SSRS reports, I believe you can just go to (Admin>Setup>Business analysis>Reporting Services>Reporting Servers" and point to your SSRS instance, and create the "Dynamics AX" data source.

You might need to do Kerberos setup too depending on your environment topology.

Comment: It's easier than Morphx reports, you just need to know the concept of SQL Select queries if you'll implement Stored Procedures as Data Source. but it's way more easier than Morphx and Morphx reports departed from AX 2012 so it's nice to learn how to use SSRS for the future releases

Answer (score 1):

The best alternative options is by far Reporting Services. It is supported by Dynamics AX 2009 in a way there there is tools and platforms to develop reports than honor the security from within AX and also the important feature of being able to persist the report design back to the Application Object Tree (under Report Libraries).

How to setup and configure SSRS for Dynamics AX 2009 is a topic on it's own, but there should be plenty of good resources out there to help you.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous answers you can use any report designer you like if you are going working with database directly.

But be ready some of axapta features will not be working automatically, for example - labels for enum values.

Comment: The drawback with this solution is security trimming is lost, and there is no good way to persist the report definition itself in the AOT. Consider if you were merging to a new SSRS instance and redeploying standard and customized SSRS reports. Deploying from the AOT would be easy, but your "outside" reports would need to be handled manually.

Answer (score 1):

Great place to start with SSRS using Visual Studio 2008 are screencasts available on youtube, just go onto youtube and search for "AX2009 SSRS".

Answer (score 0):

SSRS is fine for periodic reporting, however "online" reporting - such as invoices, pick lists, etc (anything printed when posting) is better off handled by external software. You may wish to print to file or to a DB and use 3rd party software to pick up the design/formatting.

Bottomline's Create Forms is one example I have seen used. You also have workflow options which is great when you have different companies/customers/suppliers with difference requirements, even better if you have multiple brands within the same company.

Comment: Well, in AX 2012 it all is done in SSRS, including the "online" reporting. But I can imagine there are some inefficient SSRS installations out there, not performing very well. SSRS needs to be configured properly to perform satisfactory.